# Finding Highest Number from string in cell through excel formula or VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How to find the highest number from below string(Below string is in one cell only) in excel through formula or VBA?

```
1. sanjay r
2.kaustubh r
3.abc def
4. pqr dj
5.ss dd
6.sdd yy
7.ii lll
8.www eee
9.ddd dd
10.dlieis lsie
```

so with the above example, I should get the Answer as 10.

I have written below formula to get last "." in string as last number will always be highest number and all numbers has "." after it

=FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(B37,".","@",(LEN(B37)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B37,".","")))/LEN(".")))

and then i have written another formula to get number attached to last "."

=IF(ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(B37,LEN(B37)-C37+3),1)))=FALSE,LEFT(RIGHT(B37,LEN(B37)-C37+2),1),LEFT(RIGHT(B37,LEN(B37)-C37+3),2))

And This is working perfectly fine but when there will be only one record in cell e.g.

1. sanjay r

then i am getting output as "1." instead of 1 only

i tried a lot but couldn't fix this

need help here.

Comment: I'd loop through all the characters end check each one `If IsNum(Char)` and if it is, check if a variable called `maxnum` is lower, if so, make `maxnum = Char` Thought this would only work from 0 to 9. If there are 2 digit numbers or more this doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean with highest value, in other words, what is your desired result here? What did you try and can you include your own attempt please.

Comment: there sometime will be single-digit and sometimes double-digit. and in the above example, as a result, I should get 10

Comment: And your own attempt?

Comment: adding my own attempt in the question itself in next 5 mins

Comment: updated my attempt in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `B1`, formula copied down :

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-MID(A1,IFERROR(1-LOOKUP(,-FIND(CHAR(10),A1,ROW(A:A))),1),ROW($1:$9)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton. This is exactly what I am looking for. Currently, I am not understanding how this formula is working however I will study this. Thanks once again